# parsing issues with comments: // causes errors while /* does not

Tags: c

I'm working on a large scale project and encountered this error: *`error: expected expression before '/' token`*

This happened when trying to comment out a line on my code using `// ...`. The error disappeared when I replaced it with `/* ... */`

From what I know, both of the comment formats are legal:

> 1 Except within a character constant, a string literal, or a comment, the characters /* introduce a comment. The contents of such a comment are examined only to identify multibyte characters and to find the characters */ that terminate it.83)
>
> 2 Except within a character constant, a string literal, or a comment, the characters // introduce a comment that includes all multibyte characters up to, but not including, the next new-line character. The contents of such a comment are examined only to identify multibyte characters and to find the terminating new-line character.

Is this a platform specific issue?

**EDIT :** my project is compiled with `gnu compiler` and with the following flags: `-ansi -fno-zero-initialized-in-bss  -Wall`. Replacing the `-ansi` with `-std=c99` (or more up-to-date version) solves the problem.

Comment: Try compiling your  code with option `-std=c99`.

Comment: Your C compiler could be ancient, those do not like the "C++ style comments".

Comment: Does this mean that `//` is a somewhat new addition to C?

Comment: If you consider 17 years old "new".

Comment: @ClsForCookies it was added in C99, so *new* is kind of *relative*. Less than 20 years, oh well.

Comment: That's why the __somewhat__  :) I work on a very old code

Comment: Specifying the actual compiler type and version is the only relevant information, and it's missing from the question.

Comment: @ClsForCookies you might want to check the build system then. I have some not-so-old code myself that's compiled with `-std=c89` to keep it compatible with `msvc`. I don't do this any more as I consider Microsoft's C support a lost case now...

Comment: Added details about the compiler flags. That indeed was the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single line comment `//` is introduced in C99. If you're using GCC or Clang, compile your program with the option `-std=c99` or `-std=c11`.

n1256-Foreword (p5):

> Major changes from the previous edition include:
>   [...]
>    — `//` comments
>   [...]

Comment: Or, if already fiddling with the build system, why not go directly for `-std=c11`? :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen; Yes. I thought the answer is in c99 context so simply give the option `-std=c99`.